# Material UI - Override styles dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a lot of styles declared this way:

```
const styles = () => ({
  filterDate: {
    flexGrow: "1 !important",
    maxWidth: "150px !important",
  },
  filterGeneralSelect: {
    flexGrow: "2 !important",
    maxWidth: "300px !important",
  },
  filterEmails: {
    flexGrow: "2 !important",
    maxWidth: "300px !important",
    width: "300px",
  },
...
...
...
```

Then I use:
`export default withStyles(styles)(AnalyticsPage);`
to apply them, but I'm trying to use a variable specifically here:

```
  searchButton: {
    width: "75px !important",
    height: "40px !important",
    fontSize: 14,
    textTransform: "none !important",
    boxShadow: "none !important",
    padding: "1px !important",
    borderTopLeftRadius: "0px !important",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: "0px !important",
    backgroundColor: "#0055d9",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#013D9D !important",
      color: "white",
    },
  },
```

I'm trying to use a variable for the backgroundColor and the hover backgroundColor, but the value I require to define what value is gonna be used on that variable comes as a prop to the component and when I change it, it still uses the initial value of that variable:

```
/* Outside the component */
let buttonColors = {
  color: '',
  hoverColor: ''
}

searchButton: {
    width: "75px !important",
    height: "40px !important",
    fontSize: 14,
    textTransform: "none !important",
    boxShadow: "none !important",
    padding: "1px !important",
    borderTopLeftRadius: "0px !important",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: "0px !important",
    backgroundColor: buttonColors.color,
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: `${buttonColors.hoverColor} !important`,
      color: "white",
    },
  },
```

And on the component I'm setting the value like this ->

```
function AnalyticsPage(props) {
  const { classes, routes, role, ids, type } = props;

  buttonColors = getSearchButtonColorsByCompanyName(ids.appsName);
...
...
...
```

I'm pretty sure that the variable is setted with the correct values but the styles doesn't got updated I tried moving to the end of the file instead of at the begining with no success. Also since these styles are passed to be used on different components I tried on a child component using inline styling exactly on the button that I require but it doesn't work either.

```
<Button
  className={classes.searchButton}
  aria-controls="customized-menu"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
  style={{
    backgroundColor: `${buttonColors.color} !important`,
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: `${buttonColors.hoverColor} !important`,
      color: "white",
    }
  }}
>
```

I'll appreciate any help, thanks in advice!

Comment: Have a look at this: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props You have to use `makeStyles()` in combination with a function as the value of `searchButton`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was requiring sir, thank you very much!!!!